# Text Link to Trigger Light Box

Tags: text, hyperlink, slideshow

I am considering buying the pro version of this plugin, but I want to confirm that I would be able to create a text link , such as "CLICK HERE" that will trigger a lightbox slider show to pop up.  Can this plugin does this easily?

Answer (score 0):

There are a LOT of light box plugins and code snips, so it is tough to say, but you should be able to utilize some jQuery javascript to manipulate the click event to do what you desire to do. You could make a div area to hide until needed to show the lightbox, if needed, or just inject it into the body of the document...

```
<script>
     $('popupDiv').hide();
    var lightboxCode = '<span>Whatever code your plugin uses to display here</span>';
    $('#showButton').click( function() {
        $('popupDiv').html(lightboxcode);
        $('popupDiv').show();
    });
</script>
```